# Able to update another select element value when selected one element's value and vice versa using selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am trying to update second select element value when we select the first select element value,both having the same set of options.So far, I was able to do this but when trying to update the first select element value by selecting the second select element value,it did not work.I have used selectize.js for both the elements.I have no idea what is wrong.I need help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var selector,selector1;
selector=  $('.name_month').selectize({
    onChange: function(value) {
      selector1[0].selectize.setValue(value);
   
    }      
  });  
selector1=$('.name_month1').selectize({
   /* onChange:function(value){
        selector[0].selectize.setValue(value);
   
      }*/
    });  
})
```

```css
.width_box{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap:40px;
  width:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-drag_drop.multi > .selectize-input > div.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  visibility: visible !important;
  background: #f2f2f2 !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px 4px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px 4px #ffffff;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-drag_drop .ui-sortable-placeholder::after {
  content: '!';
  visibility: hidden;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-drag_drop .ui-sortable-helper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.selectize-dropdown-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.selectize-dropdown-header-close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #303030;
  opacity: 0.4;
  margin-top: -12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
.selectize-dropdown-header-close:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
.selectize-dropdown.plugin-optgroup_columns .optgroup {
  border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-top: 0 none;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.selectize-dropdown.plugin-optgroup_columns .optgroup:last-child {
  border-right: 0 none;
}
.selectize-dropdown.plugin-optgroup_columns .optgroup:before {
  display: none;
}
.selectize-dropdown.plugin-optgroup_columns .optgroup-header {
  border-top: 0 none;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-remove_button [data-value] {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 24px !important;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-remove_button [data-value] .remove {
  z-index: 1;
  /* fixes ie bug (see #392) */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 0 0 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-remove_button [data-value] .remove:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.selectize-control.plugin-remove_button [data-value].active .remove {
  border-left-color: #cacaca;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-remove_button .disabled [data-value] .remove:hover {
  background: none;
}
.selectize-control.plugin-remove_button .disabled [data-value] .remove {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}
.selectize-control {
  position: relative;
}
.selectize-dropdown,
.selectize-input,
.selectize-input input {
  color: #303030;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
}
.selectize-input,
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input.input-active {
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: text;
  display: inline-block;
}
.selectize-input {
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input.has-items {
  padding: 6px 8px 3px;
}
.selectize-input.full {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.selectize-input.disabled,
.selectize-input.disabled * {
  cursor: default !important;
}
.selectize-input.focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.selectize-input.dropdown-active {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
.selectize-input > * {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input > div {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #303030;
  border: 0 solid #d0d0d0;
}
.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input > div.active {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  color: #303030;
  border: 0 solid #cacaca;
}
.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input.disabled > div,
.selectize-control.multi .selectize-input.disabled > div.active {
  color: #7d7d7d;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 0 solid #ffffff;
}
.selectize-input > input {
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  min-height: 0 !important;
  max-height: none !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0 !important;
  text-indent: 0 !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
  background: none !important;
  line-height: inherit !important;
  -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.selectize-input > input::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
.selectize-input > input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
.selectize-input::after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  clear: left;
}
.selectize-input.dropdown-active::before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.selectize-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  border-top: 0 none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
.selectize-dropdown [data-selectable] {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.selectize-dropdown [data-selectable] .highlight {
  background: rgba(125, 168, 208, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.selectize-dropdown [data-selectable],
.selectize-dropdown .optgroup-header {
  padding: 5px 8px;
}
.selectize-dropdown .optgroup:first-child .optgroup-header {
  border-top: 0 none;
}
.selectize-dropdown .optgroup-header {
  color: #303030;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: default;
}
.selectize-dropdown .active {
  background-color: #f5fafd;
  color: #495c68;
}
.selectize-dropdown .active.create {
  color: #495c68;
}
.selectize-dropdown .create {
  color: rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.5);
}
.selectize-dropdown-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input,
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input.input-active,
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input.input-active input {
  cursor: text;
}
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #808080 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.selectize-control.single .selectize-input.dropdown-active:after {
  margin-top: -4px;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #808080 transparent;
}
.selectize-control.rtl.single .selectize-input:after {
  left: 15px;
  right: auto;
}
.selectize-control.rtl .selectize-input > input {
  margin: 0 4px 0 -2px !important;
}
.selectize-control .selectize-input.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.1/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<div class="width_box">
<select class="name_month">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="jan">January</option>
  <option value="feb">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
</select>  
<select class="name_month1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="jan">January</option>
  <option value="feb">February</option>
  <option value="march">March</option>
</select>  
</div>
```

When I try to do the same for another element it is not working.It throws error saying too many recursion (when I ran in the code snippet).You can uncomment the part and check.Hope I am not doing anything stupid.Kindly review the snippet.Thank you.

Comment: Yes... it's infinite action error...

Comment: Is there any way to solve it?